# Getting error 401 when using httr get

Tags: r, httr

I am trying to use R to access a web page in our organization using httr GET.

However i get a message that "Access is denied due to invalid credentials".
I can do the desired action manually.
it seems that authorization is done automatically when i use internet explorer to get to the web site but the access is blocked when trying to do the same action through R.

This is how i'm trying to do it:
(I can't supply the exact address because it's an intranet address which can be used only inside the organization the same for the proxy address)

```
library(httr)
r <- GET(myurl, useproxy(myproxyid, 80), verbose())

-> GET http: //myurl
-> host: xxx
-> User-Agent : libcurl...
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, *.*
<- HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
<- Content-Type: text/html
<- Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
<- WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
<- WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
<- X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

r

Response [myurl]
Date
Status: 401
...
<title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>

....
```

I understand that i somehow have to send my credentials with my request.
is it possible to somehow use automatic authentication?

Thanks
Rafael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK

I finally made it.

I had to supply authentication data to my get command like this:

```
library(httr)
r <- GET(myurl, 
         useproxy(myproxyid, 80), 
         verbose(), 
         authenticate(user = "myuserid", password = "mypassword", type = "ntlm"))
```

I hope it helps anybody

Thanks

Rafael

Comment: Can I ask how did you get your proxy details? I am in the same boat but I don't know what my organizations details are, can it be found by inspecting the website where I usually put in my credentials?